# How can I get word and/or character count of a epub file coming as IFormFile, .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, epub

I am getting epub files as IFormFile, taking them from frontend by uploading files. I want to get character count of that epubs. There are some packages openning epub files but they need path. I do not have path, epub files are not inside my project and with IFormFile, path is not coming, it is only fakepath. Because modern browsers does not give full path of uploaded files due to security reasons. So, is there anyway that I can reach content of an epub by streams or anything else which coming as IFormFile without a path?

Comment: If your library requires a file, then you'd have to save `IFormFile` to disk.   (there's various methods in that interface to accomplish that)  That said, a properly written library would not require a physical file to exist, but would allow you to stream it directly, in which case you wouldn't have to save to disk.  Also, as an aside, the full path not being available -- while indeed a security/privacy measure -- is not relevant to your problem as it's not like having the full path would allow you to go download it from your user's computer directly.

Comment: @KirkWoll I just tho if I know the full path, I can count characters as epub uploaded. Libraries I faced were requiring path to open epub but I will look up for the ones which can do it with streams. Saving to disk is an idea in my mind now, but it will be my last bullet. Thanks for your comment.